# Refresh link so it doesn't have an id.- mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I have a website and in my test view I have a link to the sections that belongs to a test.
so If i click this the link is build up like this:

/TestSection/Index/1

now since I also want to see all sections and not only the ones that are linked to a test I did this in my controller

```
 public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "id")]int? test)
    {
        int id = test ?? 0;

        if (id != 0)
        {
            var testsection = db.testsection.Include(t => t.section).Include(t => t.test).Where(t => t.testid == id);
            return View(testsection.ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            var testsection = db.testsection.Include(t => t.section).Include(t => t.test);
            return View(testsection.ToList());
        }

    }
```

so when I go to this

/TestSection

is shows all the section

**NOW**

when i am on
/TestSection/Index/1 and i click the link that is supposed to go to /TestSection it stay's on /TestSection/Index/1

how can I fix it , the link to /TestSection works when I am on another page like /Prospect.

Thanks

**update**

these are the actionlinks:

@Html.ActionLink("Sections", "Index", "TestSection", new { id = item.id }, null) to go to
/TestSection/Index/1

@Html.ActionLink("Test section", "Index", "TestSection") that should go to /TestSection

Comment: Can you please specify your requirement in more details

Comment: Can you post the View code where you generate the link?

Comment: oke so when I use the actionlink that set's an id, i navigate to /TestSection/Index/1 for example. now when I have a nav bar at the top of the website where I have a actionlink to /TestSection. But when I am on /TestSection/Index/1 and press my link in my nav bar it stay's /TestSection/Index/1 instead of going to /TestSection

Comment: Can you please show the code for route configuration

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );